# How to optimize a MySQL/MyISAM full text search with many results

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search, bigdata

I have a MySQL MyISAM table with a full text index on the keywords column and 20 millions rows. It works well when a search for rare words, for example:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST ('+DUCK' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(0.005s, 2k results)

But when I search for a more common terms it is much slowers:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST ('+YES' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(5s, 2millions results)

It makes sens because the last one returns much more rows, but then how can I pre-filter the rows before the text search? This doesn't work:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE date > "2019-09-23" AND MATCH(keywords) AGAINST ('+YES' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(5s, 0 result)

Comment: i would suggested dropping MyISAM as MySQL devs are preparing MyISAM to be deprecated and removed (maybe pretty soon) it as InnoDB outperform MyiSAM (if configured correcty) by miles ..  Why do i think MySQL devs are preparing  MyISAM to be deprecated? Well there is a hint in the MySQL manual when MySQL needs to process queries with (disk) based temporary table you always was able to set the [internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine)

Comment: ... But notice *"In MySQL 8.0.16 and later, on-disk internal temporary tables always use the InnoDB storage engine; as of MySQL 8.0.16, this variable has been removed and is thus no longer supported. "*

Comment: I switched to MyISAM because the performance in general were horrible with InnoDB. I use MySQL 5.7. The first query for example could take 1s to run (0.005s with MyISAM)

Comment: Btw, `YES` is a stopword in MyISAM FTS. So it never gets indexed; nor searching on it will return any result. So basically, no word is being searched upon and that is why it seems like a full table scan happening. Check the full list of stopwords here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-myisam-search-indexes

Comment: good catch @MadhurBhaiya i didn't notice that... Anyhow topticstarter i know for sure then you didn't configure MySQL for InnoDB usage then if you claim/tested MyISAM to be faster then InnoDB...  But besides stopwords you also have to deal with [Minimum and Maximum Word Length settings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length) as the [ft_min_word_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) setting defaults to 4 so if you remove `yes` from the stopword list it is still not indexed..

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM's (and maybe InnoDB's) FULLTEXT will always do the MATCH first, then any other clauses.  Hence, adding that extra filter does not help with speed.

Think of it this way...  A FT index is constructed to test the entire table(s) for the MATCH clause.  It is not ready to handle any filtering *before* it goes to work.  So, you are stuck with FT first, then filter the results the other way but without benefit of any indexes.